# Replacing each of letters of string with span

Tags: reactjs

I have a string named for example 'just a simple text' and want to replace each of letters with span. 
ES6 code that is working in console in the browser -> [...text] gives me an expected result - an array with every letter separately.

```
const text = 'just a simple text';
[...text].map( letter => <span>letter</span>)
```

When I do this in react:

```
const Heading = () => {
    const text = useState('Just a simple text');

    const myLetter = React.createRef();
    const myWrapper = React.createRef();

    return (
        <StyledWrapper ref={myWrapper}>
            {[...text].map(letter => (
                <StyledLetter ref={myLetter}>{letter}</StyledLetter>
            ))}
        </StyledWrapper>
    );
};
```

I got `<span>just a simple text</span>`.

Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of  from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.

I've heard something about High Order Components but don't know exactly how it works yet. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

[useState()](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usestate) returns a tuple `[state, setState]`

so when you spread `[...text]` you get `['Just a simple text', setState]`

When you call `.map()` on this you will get `letter` as `setState` function, that's where the error `Functions are not valid as a React child` comes from.

so

```
const text = useState('Just a simple text');
```

should be

```
const [text, setText] = useState('Just a simple text');
```

Comment: @KacperFaligowski what error do you see?
please check the following https://codesandbox.io/s/dark-smoke-ku6f0

Comment: I fix that. I have wrapped my letters with span but can't animate this https://codesandbox.io/s/cool-cori-km8rc.

Comment: I want to have an animation using animejs like this: https://tobiasahlin.com/moving-letters/#13

Comment: If your issue is about animejs. You should ask a new question specific for your issue.
From what I see from your codesandbox, the error tells you that `myNode` and `letter` are null because you accessed `myWrapper.current` and `myLetter.current` before the component was mounted, to solve this specific error, you can move `myNode` and `letter` assignment inside `useEffect()`